# selenium findElements returning a non-working array

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

```
browser.get('http://example.net/');
ps = browser.$$('p');
// shows an array of objects

ps[0];
// shows undefined

ps. // hit tab
// shows lots of things, including
// ps.0 ps.1

Object.keys(ps);
// shows [ 'locator_', 'parentElementFinder_' ]
```

same with

```
ps = browser.driver.findElements(By.css('p'))
```

except Object.keys(ps) shows methods of a promise. Resolving the promise didn't help.

The most confusing part is that the return value looks like an array on inspection but accessing any of its properties or functions results in undefined.

I should add that I'm using protractor (and set browser.ignoreSynchronization = true). I'm on ubuntu 14.04 with default-jdk. My selenium is 2.0 installed along with protractor.

Comment: `"My selenium is 2.0"` selenium is [now](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.42/) at version 2.42

Comment: Where are you playing with this? in Protractor's elementexplorer ?

Comment: Why don't just use `.get(idx)` like this: `$$('p').get(0);`

Comment: Also, you should try to perform an action on the element promise, e.g. `$$('p').get(0).getText();` or `$$('p').get(0).isPresent();`